# Simple dynamic Transpose 2 column as 2 rows in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to transpose powerunit_natlang and transmission_natlang columns. 
Please someone help me.

```
create table #urgent_2_11
(
     id int,
     cc_key varchar(50),
     technical_item_name_natlang varchar(50),
     modeltrim_name varchar(50),
     powerunit_natlang varchar(50),
     transmission_natlang varchar(50),
     category_name_natlang varchar(50)
)

insert into #urgent_2_11 
values(12017,'28c6483296abe739646b0b91b1d17fb4','Cilindrada','like','1,0 MPI 75 CV','Auto 5 vel.','Motorización y transmisión')

insert into #urgent_2_11 
values(12022,'28c6483296abe739646b0b91b1d17fb4','Cilindrada','Like','1,0 MPI 75 CV','Manual 5 vel.','Motorización y transmisión')

insert into #urgent_2_11   
values(12013,'28c6483296abe739646b0b91b1d17fb4','Largo','Like','1,0 MPI 75 CV','Manual 5 vel.','Dimensiones exteriores')

insert into #urgent_2_11 
values(12014,'28c6483296abe739646b0b91b1d17fb4','Ancho','Like','1,0 MPI 75 CV','Manual 5 vel.','Dimensiones exteriores')

insert into #urgent_2_11  
values(12015,'28c6483296abe739646b0b91b1d17fb4','Alto','Like','1,0 MPI 75 CV','Manual 5 vel.','Dimensiones exteriores')

insert into #urgent_2_11 
values(12016,'28c6483296abe739646b0b91b1d17fb4','Distancia entre ejes','Like','1,0 MPI 75 CV','Manual 5 vel.','Dimensiones exteriores')

select * 
from #urgent_2_11
```

Please see here for the expected output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2FAm.png)

[enter link description here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112357320599086430677/posts/bu5kWJag4rf?pid=6323036400128675346&oid=112357320599086430677)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT 
        t1.technical_item_name_natlang
        ,t1.category_name_natlang
    ,CASE t1.technical_item_name_natlang 
        WHEN 'Cilindrada' THEN 'Like'
        WHEN 'Largo' THEN ''
        WHEN 'Ancho' THEN ''
        WHEN 'Alto' THEN ''
        WHEN 'Distancia entre ejes' THEN '' 
        END AS [Auto 5 vel.]
    ,CASE t1.category_name_natlang
        WHEN 'Motorización y transmisión' THEN 'Like'
        WHEN 'Dimensiones exteriores' THEN 'Like'
        END AS [Manual 5 vel.]  
    FROM #urgent_2_11 as t1
    GO
```